# Gnuplot image to movie: Twinkling effect

Tags: gnuplot, avconv, movies

I made png images using gnuplot:

```
do for [i=1:imax]{
   imagefile='M'.sprintf("%5.5i",i).'.png'
   datafile='A'.sprintf("%5.5i",j).'.dat'
   plot datafile u 2:3:(rad*$6) with circles lc rgb "black" lw 3
   pause 0
}
```

Then I used avconv to create movies:

```
avconv -r $1 -i M%05d.png -c:v libx264 final_simulation.mp4
```

However, my movies appear to have a twinkling effect in the circles and not smooth as a normal movie might look like. Is there any remedy for this?

Comment: this is difficult to reproduce if there is no test data. Did you know that gnuplot can do animated GIFs? Maybe this could be an alternative?. Check `help gif`, option `animate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand your dilemma. However the journal that I am submitting to only accepts these formats: MPG, MOV, AVI, WMV, MP4.

Comment: @theozh if you could provide me a general routine you use to generate movies from image files that would be great too.

Comment: Have you tried using ffmpeg? I usually generate a bunch of .png files and just glue them together using 
ffmpeg -start_number 0 -i 'frame_%d.png' -c:v libx264 motion.mp4 
P.S. this problem can also be related to the parameters of your video, meaning that you have just a few frames per second.

Comment: I also ended up to use ffmpeg, so @vladimir advice is nice. For instance, I save my file as `set output sprintf('%07d.png', i)`, where `i` is the number of iterations. At the end I glue all my captions using `ffmpeg -i %07d.png animation.avi`. It is basic, but it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir. I use a gnuplot script to create those .png images. I seems that gnuplot mishandles the images somehow and produces sequence of images that themselves have circles growing an shrinking in size. do you have any tips for this?

Comment: @sagniksingha I'm not sure that I understand this correctly, however, I suspect that your output files simply have low resolution. As long as your column $6 is constant you should have the same radius everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir. But is there a way to increase the resolution if the images(.png) that gnuplot outputs?

Comment: @sagniksingha yes, just `set term png size x,y` where x & y are your dimensions in pixels. I also prefer pngcairo instead of regular png terminal, it seems to have better quality. Do not forget to change the size of all your fonts (if any) and make your lines thicker to be visible.

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks for your advice. But can .eps files be converted to movies?

Comment: @sagniksingha eps? you should have png as output. AFAIK, no, since eps is a vector format. You have to convert it to, say, png, first, thus, it's easier to make png files in the first place.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you sir. It was just a question I asked out of curiosity since using .eps outputs we get really good resolution images/plots. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

gnuplot can generate animated gifs. Well, there is still a slight flickering. I'm not sure, maybe you can get rid of it with external converters when converting to the desired format.

For example, with this code:

```
### animation 
reset session

set term gif size 500,400 animate delay 10 optimize 
set output "AnimatedCircle.gif"

set yrange[-1.5:1.5]
set xrange[0:1]

imax = 100.
do for [i=0:imax] {
    plot '+' u (i/imax):(sin(2*pi*i/imax)):(0.1) \
    with circles lc rgb "black" lw 3 title sprintf("Circle %d",i)
}
set output
### end of code
```

you'll get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @theozh for the code. This miraculously doesn't have the twinkling effect. I'll give the gif verison a try. However, the issue of submission in the formats I mentioned still remains.

Comment: as @Vladimir suggests above, ffmpeg can convert a lot of formats. For example, animated GIF to all of your formats mentioned above (except WMV). Via gnuplot animated GIF, you don't have to generate hundreds of temporary PNGs.

Comment: thanks for the help, but if you look closely there is still twinkling...

Comment: you can check it in the link I posted as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

[Concentric circles created using the same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBVAD.gif)

Please have a look @theozh